# Angular-cli specifying file names for production environment

Tags: angular

Angular is generating random names for the files when running `ng build --prod`. **Is there a way to specify the names we want?** We are using `angular-cli`. We really need this as our angular application is embedded inside a CMS platform.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you build in dev mode, files will get the standard names like inline.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js, main.bundle.js, etc. To build in production mode, use the `--prod` flag:

```
ng build --prod
```

You can use the following flags to prevent file name hashing in production mode:

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing none
```

Read more about "build" and its command line options [on the Angular docs site](https://angular.io/cli/build).

Comment: this is working, but the css styles are not getting bundled in .js. how can I keep this feature?

Comment: Hey bro, I think this is the command you need                                                 
         ng build -prod --output-hashing none -ec false more info here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: IMO `-prod` should be `--prod`, isn't it?

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question - how do we specify the names? this omits hashing, but how do we name the files ourselves? (After reading again, we prob can't specify the names..just omit the hashcodes).

Comment: angular-cli updated the command: ng build --prod --output-hashing none --extract-css false

Answer (score 1):

ng build FooBar --out-hasing none
will do what you want but if you dont want to keep typing "--out-hasing none" each time you build, you can set the "outputHasing" property to "none" right in the angular.json file
[image]

Comment: works perfectly, except for the typo "outputHasing" in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible by setting up `namedChunks: true` in the file `angular.json`. It will leave generated readable name for chanks, same as you see when starting a project by `ng start`